# How does one add local @client schema extension to apollo-codegen

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm using [apollo-link-state to add local state](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state.html#schema), that adds some fields to the query root, and I supply a `typeDef` that looks something like this:

```
extend type Query {
    foo: String
}
```

I'm also using [apollo-codegen to add flow annotations](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/developer-tooling.html#generate). However, it doesn't apply the extension, and returns an error:

```
.../src/components/Foo/Foo.js: Cannot query field "foo" on type "Query".
```

when it encounters a query to the extended field:

```
query FooQuery {
    foo @client
}
```

So my question is: how do I tell `apollo-codegen` about the client extensions?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so according to [this issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-codegen/issues/366) there *isn't* a build-in way yet. Inspired by [zhenwenc's gist](https://gist.github.com/zhenwenc/09c9e78faefa4c35bdff6280a010ab81), I wrote a quick script to merge server and client schemas:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const { introspectionFromSchema } = require("graphql/utilities");
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require("graphql-tools");
const { fileLoader, mergeTypes } = require("merge-graphql-schemas");

// Make sure unhandled errors in async code are propagated correctly
process.on("uncaughtException", error => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exit(1);
});

process.on("unhandledRejection", error => {
  throw error;
});

async function introspectSchema(input, output) {
  const schemas = [].concat(...input.map(i => fileLoader(i)));
  const typeDefs = mergeTypes(schemas, {
    all: true
  });

  const schema = await makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs,
    resolverValidationOptions: { requireResolversForResolveType: false }
  });
  const introspection = await introspectionFromSchema(schema);
  const json = JSON.stringify(introspection, null, 2);
  fs.writeFileSync(output, json);
}

const input = [
  path.join(__dirname, "../data/*.graphql"),
  path.join(__dirname, "../src/*.graphql")
];

const output = path.join(__dirname, "../src/__generated__/schema.json");

// Generate an introspection JSON format from remote GraphQL server merging
// with any local GraphQL schemas
introspectSchema(input, output, true);
```

and call it before running the codegen:

```
node scripts/merge.js && \
apollo-codegen generate src/components/**/*.js \
  --schema src/__generated__/schema.json \
  --target flow-modern \
  --add-typename \
  --use-flow-exact-objects false \
  --use-flow-read-only-types true
```

Note that this does NOT validate that queries to the client schema use the `@client` directive, which would be a huge perk of first-class support. However, this will at least keep the generated types working!